How is the retarded Green's function modified under the action of time-reversal operator?
Suppose I have a time-reversal symmetric Hamiltonian,
$$\hat{H} = \sum_{\vec p} \begin{pmatrix}
c^\dagger_{\vec p,\uparrow} & c^\dagger_{\vec p,\downarrow} 
\end{pmatrix} \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{p^2}{2m}-\mu & 0 \\
0 & \frac{p^2}{2m}-\mu 
\end{pmatrix}}_{H(\vec p)}  \begin{pmatrix}
c_{\vec p, \uparrow} \\
c_{\vec p, \downarrow} 
\end{pmatrix}.  $$
This is invariant under the time reversal. In the single-particle basis, the time-reversal operator takes the form, $T = U \mathcal{K}$, with $U = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}  =-i\sigma_y$, and $K$ is the complex conjugation operator. It can be readily verified that $T H(\vec p) T^{-1} = H^*(-\vec p)$.
The density of states is given by the imaginary part of the retarded Green's function,
$$
N(\vec r, \omega) = \frac{1}{\pi} \text{Im}[{\text{tr}}[G^R(\vec r, \vec r, \omega)]],$$
where $$G^R(\vec r, \vec r, \omega) = \int \frac{d^d p}{(2\pi)^d} \left[\left(\omega + i 0^+\right) I_{2\times 2} - \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{p^2}{2m}-\mu & 0 \\
0 & \frac{p^2}{2m}-\mu 
\end{pmatrix} \right]^{-1}.$$
The Green's function commutes with $U$, but its imaginary part changes at the application of the complex-conjugate operator.
This seems to imply that $T G^R(\omega)  T^{-1} = (G^{R}(\omega))^*$, i.e., $N(\vec r,\omega) \rightarrow -N(\vec r,\omega)$ under time-reversal.
However, since the system is symmetric under time-reversal, the density of states should be invariant under the application of the time-reversal operator (it should not acquire a negative sign).
In that case, is it wrong to conclude that the Green's function transforms as $G^R(\omega) \rightarrow U \mathcal{K} G^R(\omega) \mathcal{K} U^\dagger$? What should be the correct relation so that the density of states remains invariant under time-reversal?

The retarded and advanced Green functions are interchanged under time reversal. It isn't the theory itself that breaks time reversal symmetry, it's the definition of the retarded (or advanced) propagator.
Consider a simple classical field theory describing fields $\psi(x,t)$ subjected to arbitrary classical source field(s) $J$, $J^\dagger$ with time-reversal-invariant action $S$ of the form
\begin{align*}
S[\psi;J] = \psi^\dagger M\psi + J^\dagger \psi + \psi^\dagger J
\end{align*}
Varying the action with respect to $\psi$, you find
\begin{align*}
\delta S = 0 & \Rightarrow \frac{\delta S}{\delta \psi^\dagger} = 0\\
& \Rightarrow M\psi + J = 0,\\
& \text{i.e.}\quad \psi = -M^{-1}J.
\end{align*}
In practice, the last equation must be interpreted carefully because $M^{-1}$ isn't always well-defined.  In physics, it is standard to introduce a regularizer (doesn't that word sound like it tunneled from the Mad Max universe?) to $M^{-1}$ to ensure that $\psi(x,t)$ does not depend on values of $J$ outside of a certain causal horizon (e.g. a light half-cone, for relativistic physics, or a half-space, for Galilean or non-relativistic physics.)  Let's suppose that $M_R^{-1}$ is the regularized version of $M^{-1}$ that respects causality. Then almost by definition, $M_R^{-1}$ breaks time-reversal invariance: if you reverse time under the mapping $T\psi(x,t) = \psi(x,-t)$, say, then (interpreting $T$ as a "matrix")  $TM_R^{-1}T$ is in effect anticausal (or advanced, in perfectly conventional language.)  That is, the causal propagator $M_R^{-1}$ maps to the advanced propagator $M_A^{-1}$ under time reversal (where $M_A^{-1}$ is regularized to have support over a "dual" causal space.)
In time-reversal invariant homogeneous theories, you will find that $M_A^{-1}(x,t) = M_R^{-1}(x, -t)$ (where both are interpreted as homogeneous integral kernels.) Thus, if $N(x, \omega) = \Im[M_R^{-1}(0,\omega)]$, where $M_R^{-1}(0,\omega) = \int_{\mathbb R} dt e^{i\omega t} M_R^{-1}(0,t)$, then
\begin{align*}
\Im[M_A^{-1}(0,\omega)] &= \Im[\int dt_{-\infty}^\infty M_A^{-1}(0, t) e^{i\omega t} dt]\\
& = \Im[\int_{-\infty}^\infty M_R^{-1}(0, -t) e^{i\omega t} dt]\\
& = \Im[\int_{\infty}^{-\infty} M_R^{-1}(0, u) e^{-i\omega u} (-du)]\\
& = \Im[M_R^{-1}(0,-\omega)]
\end{align*}
where because of the form of the regularizer required for causality the last expression is typically not equal to $\Im [M_R^{-1}(0,\omega)]$
(For fields with spin components, time reversal will also transpose/swap positive and negative components of the causal and anti-causal propagators, and so the generality of the terms used in the above argument depends somewhat on the definition of the advanced/anti-causal propagator for spin fields.)

But, isn't density of states always the imaginary part of the retarded (and not the advanced) Green's function?

I think the retarded Green's function of the time-reversed theory would be the time-reversed advanced Green's function of the original theory.  If you take the imaginary part of the time-reversed retarded Green's function, you would be computing the imaginary part of the advanced Green's function of the time-reversed theory.

Can you add that to the answer?


The density of states is given by the imaginary part of the retarded Green's function,
$$
N(\vec r, \omega) = \frac{1}{\pi} \text{Im}[{\text{tr}}[G^R(\vec r, \vec r, \omega)]];,$$
where $$G^R(\vec r, \vec r, \omega) = \int \frac{d^d p}{(2\pi)^d} \left[\left(\omega + i 0^+\right) I_{2\times 2} - \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{p^2}{2m}-\mu & 0 \\
0 & \frac{p^2}{2m}-\mu 
\end{pmatrix} \right]^{-1}.$$

First of all, this seems to already have a sign error.
Since your $G^R$ has a $+i0^+$ in the denominator, it has a $-i0^+$ in the numerator when you complete the square, and therefore the correct expression is:
$$
N(\vec r, \omega) = -\frac{1}{\pi} \text{Im}[{\text{tr}}[G^R(\vec r, \vec r, \omega)]]\;.
$$
But, nevertheless, this does not solve your issue of the RHS of the above equation changing sign under time reversal.

Please consider the alternative:
$$
N(\vec r, \omega) = \frac{1}{\pi}| \text{Im}[{\text{tr}}[G^R(\vec r, \vec r, \omega)]]|\;.
$$
This is manifestly positive just like a density of state should be, by definition.

Please also recall the definition of the density of states as a manifestly positive quantity (where I am now suppressing the spatial variable and matrix indices for convenience):
$$
N(\omega) = \sum_i \delta(\omega - E_i) 
$$
$$
=-\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_i Im\left(\frac{1}{\omega - E_i + i\epsilon}\right)
$$
$$
=-\frac{1}{\pi}Im G^R
$$
$$
=+\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_i Im\left(\frac{1}{\omega - E_i - i\epsilon}\right)
$$
$$
=+\frac{1}{\pi}Im G^A
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{\pi}|Im G^{R,A}|
$$

There was a sign error in my original post, it should really be $-\frac{1}{\pi} \text{Im}[{\text{tr}}[G^R(\vec r, \vec r, \omega)]]$, Thank you for your suggestion regarding using the manifestly positive quantity,
